# How parse function arguments effectively?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an `async` function that takes a single non optional parameter, that parameter can either be `"all"` (a string) or can be an integer. How do I handle it effectively without writing redundant code.

Here's a similar function:

```py
async def myfunc(para):
```

I can process this later on easily like:

```py
async def myfunc(para):
    try:
        int(para)
    except ValueError:
        if not para == "all":
            print("wrong parameter")
```

I know there's way to do this just with type hinting with using `typing`, I just don't know what

Note that the string can only be `"all"`.

Do you know a better way to do this?

Comment: `if para == "all": ... elif para.isdigit(): ...`?

Comment: type hinting is just hinting for the function user to know what has to be put there, I don't think there is really another way to do this really (different approaches but not really shorter), depends on how that argument is used down the line tho

Comment: Note that type hinting won't actually apply this logic at runtime. But you're probably looking for `Union[int, Literal["all"]]`.

Comment: If `myfunc` is "basically" a function on integers, what does the exception `"all"` mean? There might be a better API design that sidesteps the issue altogether.

Comment: Better way: have a separate function which handles the "all" case, with no parameters.

Comment: @kaya3 - doesn't that just move the problem up one function? Now the caller needs to make the "all" check.

Comment: @tdelaney Now the caller doesn't need to write the string `"all"` to call the function. If somebody else is *giving* the caller either an `int` or the string `"all"` and the caller is just passing it on, then yes, the problem should be moved further up. Otherwise you have a "stringly typed" program.

Comment: @kaya3 - but that's why its not a better way.

Comment: @tdelaney It **is** better to not use particular string values as sentinels for control flow. Your definition of "better" seems to be whatever is less work, but if you start from a bad design then of course it will take work to make it a better design.

Comment: @kaya3 - I don't see why not. Python is a dynamic language after all. Its quite common to use `None` in a scenario like this. "all" may be perfectly reasonable in this particular design.

Comment: @kaya3 - and anyway, that's a complete change of subject. Its still generally not a good idea to implement a completely different function just because part of it takes different path on an `if`.

Comment: @tdelaney I haven't proposed any such principle; the principle I've proposed is that one shouldn't pass around string-valued sentinels in order to determine the behaviour of a function.

Comment: @tdelaney It's a very good idea. Why write a function that can accept values it can't use when you can write a function that can't accept useless values in the first place? Deciding between function A and function B is no hard than deciding whether to pass `"all"` or an integer to function C.

Comment: @chepner - So a function that accepts both a regex string and a precompiled  `re.Pattern` is wrong? The `re` module functions do just that. What about `pandas` that uses strings and integers for axis selectors? I don't think you'd flinch if OP was using `None` instead of a string. But why not a string?

Comment: @tdelaney That function doesn't do two different things. Conceptually, it turns a regex string in to a `Pattern`, then proceeds as if it originally received a `Pattern` object. Do you really think this function is turning `"all"` into a single `int`, then proceeding as if the `int` had been passed?

Comment: `None` *would* be better than `"all"`, because it's the only value of its type.

Comment: @chepner - It could easily be doing that. Suppose OP is processsing a list up to the integer index, or "all" being the full list. The point is, we don't know.

Comment: @chepner - `None` isn't necessarily the best choice, especially when pulling in configuration somewhere else. Consider YAML fragments `process_max: 3` verses `process_max: "all"`. It would be reasonable to use text in a config file instead of some archaic method of doing `None`. I don't see much difference between `None` and `"all"` in a dynamic language.

Comment: The list slice is a bad example: if you used `None`, your code could just use `some_list[slice(0, x)]` and it would work for an integer `x` *or* `None`. Converting an arbitrary string to a usable index isn't something this function should worry about.

Comment: I wouldn't design my functions around the format of any particular configuration file. Let the caller convert `"all"` to an appropriate value (or use `"all"` to decide the appropriate function to call).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
async def myfunc(para):
    if not(para == "all" or type(para)==int):
        print("Wrong parameter!")
        return
```

This only checks if the para input is valid, but does not do anything with it!!

```py
async def myfunc(para):
    if para == "all":
        #Do "all" stuff
    elif type(para) == int:
        #Do int stuff
    else:
        print("Wrong parameter!")
        return
```

This might be a bit more useful

Comment: " that parameter can either be "all" (a string) or can be an **integer**. " (emphasis mine). Passing an integer to your function results in `AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'isdigit'`

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out if i just replaced para.isdigit() with type(para)==int

Comment: I like the answer except the second example. We don't know what OP plans to do next and should not assume that there are two different algorithms here.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to admit you have two different functions:

```
# myfunc(3)
async def myfunc1(x: int) -> X:
    ...

# myfunc("all")
async def myfunc2() -> X:
    ...
```

Now you don't have the problem of passing another string aside from `"all"`, because you no longer have a function that accepts *any* string.

---

**An aside**

Since Python is a dynamically typed language, the rest of this answer will assume we are using code the successfully passes static type-checking; we assume that calls like `myfunc1("not an int")` are just as incorrect as `myfunc2(3)`.)

---

There was never nothing special about the specific string `"all"`; you could have used `"every"` or `"each"` or `"foo"`, and you would have structured the code the same way. The important thing was that `"all"` wasn't any *other* string: you really just wanted a single value that wasn't an `int`.

Taking the point further, why would you care if the caller passed any other string than `"all"`? Rather than raise an exception, you could just as easily have written

```
if para != "all":
    para = "all"
```

and proceeded.

`None` fills that role more cleanly: it's the *only* value of its type, so there's no possibility of passing an incorrect value. Now look at the following function:

```
async def myfunc2a(x: None) -> X:
    ...
```

There is only one legal way to call this function: `myfunc2a(None)`.  `None` isn't filling any semantic role here; it's there purely for syntactic reasons, because `myfunc2a` needs an argument. When that's the case, you might as well just eliminate the parameter altogether (which is legal in Python, unlike mathematical functions which are by definition mappings from an argument to a value).

```
 async def myfunc2b() -> X:
     ...
```

Comment: This answer is making a lot of assumptions about the author's design of this function. The question is _How do I handle it effectively without writing redundant code._ Implementing the same routine twice and forcing the caller to do the `if` seems like you are going in the opposite direction.

Comment: @tdelaney Read about [inversion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

Comment: I doubt there's very much redundant code if it has to handle arguments of two different types. What redundant code there is can likely be refactored into a single function that *doesn't* take arguments of different types.